# OnClick JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, conga

I use onclick javascript to use with Conga Composer instead of URL to check validations. But I do get 'The id parameter is missing' error when running the code. It looks like the url does not get the ID.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}

if('{!Enrolment_Request__c.Validation_Failed__c}' == true)
{
alert('Please check values in all required fields.');

}else{
window.location.href = '/apex/APXTConga4__Conga_Composer?SolMgr=1?id={!Enrolment_Request__c.Id}';
serverUrl="{!API.Partner_Server_URL_370}";
Id="{!Enrolment_Request__c.Id}";

QueryId="[GetContactDataforETA]a2B0M000000HP1n";

TemplateId="a2J0M000000J9D4";

DS7="1141";

CSVisible="1141";

CSRoutingType="SERIAL";

CSRecipient1="{!Enrolment_Request__c.Workplace_SignatoryId__c}";

CSRecipient2="{!Enrolment_Request__c.LSA_SignatoryId__c}";

CSRecipient3="{!Enrolment_Request__c.Trainee_SignatoryId__c}";

FlattenPDFForms="1";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a logic problem here:

```
if('{!Enrolment_Request__c.Validation_Failed__c}' == true)
```

Ironically, `"true" == true` is *false*. Instead, just change it to:

```
if({!Enrolment_Request__c.Validation_Failed__c})
```

---

All of the code past `window.location.href` isn't doing anything; you're just assigning variable values.

Instead, you need to build all your query string parameters in to the URL:

```
window.location.href = '/apex/APXTConga4__Conga_Composer?SolMgr=1&'+
 'id={!Enrolment_Request__c.Id}&'+
 'serverUrl={!API.Partner_Server_URL_370}&'+
 // rest of code...
```

Comment: All working now